# How can I make Coda auto indent between function brackets?

Tags: macos, editor, coda

I've been trying out Coda for the Mac.  I really like it, except for one thing.  It does no auto indention between brackets.  I'm use to having other editors I use to automatically close brackets and tab indent for me.  Does anyone know how to make it do this?  I really want to love Coda, but to me, this is a deal breaker if I can't get it to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Download TEA for Coda from [here](http://onecrayon.com/tea/coda/). Once installed you can use cmd+shift+enter which will move to next line and indent. Hope this helps.

(TEA is no longer maintained but is still very robust in my experience)